# Issue while installing a lower python version in conda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have python version 3.8.8 in conda. I want version 3.5.0 for a Machine learning project but when I ran the command `conda install python=3.5.0`, following output came:

**Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python=3.5.0

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.**

I am not able to comprehend this. How can I install the required python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing with `conda` is you can maintain as many versions of python as you want simultaneously but you're trying to modify the main distribution of python that comes with the `conda` that you've installed. What you should do is create a new environment with the desirable python version.

Create a new environment for your ML-related work using

```
conda create -n ml_env python=3.5.0
conda activate ml_env
```

This way, if you no longer need the stuff you installed for ML, you can easily remove the whole environment:

```
conda env remove -n ml_env
```